# HTML & CSS - Hover a DIV move it a little

Tags: html, css

I have a strange behavior in HTML + CSS: When I hover the picture it move a little (both in Chrome and ie 10). If the picture is in the top, it doesn't occuer.

This is very simple code, so I don't know what to do.

With this CSS:

```
div.effect img.image {
    /*type your css here which you want to use for both*/
}
div:hover.effect img.image {
    display: none;
}
div.effect img.hover {
    display: none;
}
div:hover.effect img.hover {
    display: block;
}
```

And this HTML:

```
<div class="effect" style="position: absolute; bottom:15px;right:135px;" title="Update from us">
   <img class="image" src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schoolslogoNEW310113.gif" />
   <img class="image hover" src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schoolslogoNEW310113.gif" />
</div>
```

You can see here in: http://jsfiddle.net/LmMSH/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you want ?????

Comment: What do you try to do? If you don't like that effect you can remove the second image with .hover. And if you don't like the effect of hide/show while hover you can remove that css

Comment: I want to change between two pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
div.effect img.image {
    /*type your css here which you want to use for both*/
    display: block;
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/LmMSH/2/

**EDIT:**

If you want to change pictures when user hover on `div` use this css:

```
img.image{
    display: block;
}

img.hover{
    display: none;
}

div.effect:hover img.image {
    display: none;
}

div.effect:hover img.hover {
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LmMSH/11/

Comment: that solution is the same that remove an image and remove the css efect. I don't see the sense of having two pictures without any effect.

Comment: yes you are right but maybe he just simplified his code and we just do not see sense

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div.effect img.image {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this CSS too

```
div{height:60px}
```